# Scope is not updated with JSON call, but updated with simple integer assign in the custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have 2 different values assigned to my $scope. One is $scope.summary which is a JSON object, and other one is $scope.myNumber which assigned to 3.

From controller:

```
myService.loadSummary(function(data) {
    $scope.summary = data;
    $scope.$apply();
});

$scope.myNumber = 3;
```

myService contains a function called loadSummary which works perfectly and I can see in debug $scope.summary gets the data that it supposed to get. I also see that $scope.myNumber is assigned to 3 in debug.

When I go to my directive in debug it only shows myNumber value. There is nothing about $scope.summary. It is undefined.

From directive:

```
define([ 'angular', 'directives-module', 'text!./tmpl/table.html' ], function(
    angular, directives, tmpl) {
    directives.directive('summaryTable', function($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            template: tmpl,
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
                require([ 'jquery', 'datagrids' ], function($) {
                    var data = scope.summary;
```

What might be the reason for it?

I have a very limited knowledge in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happens because your update should be inside `$apply()` expression, like this:

```
myService.loadSummary(function(data) {        
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.summary = data;
    });
});
```

See this nice [article](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html). Quote:

> You do need to use it (*$apply()*) if you are going to run code in a new turn. And only if that turn isn’t being created from a method in the AngularJS library. Inside that new turn, you should **wrap your code in $scope.$apply()**.